# Сохранение изображения в SQL

Tags: sql, vb.net

Написал примерный код, сохранения в SQL изображение.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    PictureBox1.Image = Clipboard.GetImage
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim im1 As Image = PictureBox1.Image
    Dim ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream
    im1.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)
    Dim md As Byte() = ms.GetBuffer

    TextBox1.Text = md.ToString

    Dim sql As String = "Insert into test1 Values(@image)"
    Dim p As New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@image", SqlDbType.Image)
    p.Value = md

    Dim cmd2 As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(sql)
    cmd2.Parameters.Add(p)

End Sub
```

Возник вопрос который я не могу проверить. При выполнении данного кода и сохранении изображения, как он будет выглядеть в самой SQL? В данный момент реализовано все в формате `rtf` и при получении данных из SQL 200+ данных, приходится парой очень долго ждать.

Comment: *как он будет выглядить в самой SQL?* Как набор байтов. PS. Не смущает, что имя параметра в одном месте `@myimage`, а в другом `@image`?

Comment: @Akina это всего лишь тест и "проблема" копирования кода

Comment: бинарные данные у вас будут в sql. Akina +

Comment: @Dmitriy хорошо. Это я понял.. а как думаете, как долго они будут грузится.. 200+ картинок к примеру в локальной сети (100 Mbit).. В данный момент, rtf грузятся 40-50 секунд

Comment: Катринки бывают и 10 кб, и 100 Мб. Так что на вопрос ответить в принципе нельзя.

Comment: @Dmitriy плюс если что можно поставить используя стрелку вверх рядом с комментарием